# Vagrant Puppet Provisioning - Pear Packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant, puppet

I'm using this Laravel Vagrant: https://github.com/bryannielsen/Laravel4-Vagrant and I want to add PHPUNIT and some other PEAR packages.

I added this line on manifests/phpbase.pp

```
include pearpackages
```

I created this file puppet/modules/pearpackages/manifests/init.pp:

```
class pearpackages {
exec {"pear upgrade":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear upgrade",
  require => Package['php-pear'],
  returns => [ 0, '', ' ']
}

# set channels to auto discover
exec { "pear auto_discover" :
  command => "/usr/bin/pear config-set auto_discover 1",
  require => [Package['php-pear']]
}

exec { "pear update-channels" :
  command => "/usr/bin/pear update-channels",
  require => [Package['php-pear']]
}

exec {"pear install phpunit":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpunit',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phploc
exec {"pear install phploc":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/phploc",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phploc',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phpcpd
exec {"pear install phpcpd":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/phpcpd",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpcpd',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phpdcd
exec {"pear install phpdcd":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/phpdcd-beta",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpdcd',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phpcs
exec {"pear install phpcs":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps PHP_CodeSniffer",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpcs',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phpdepend
exec {"pear install pdepend":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend-beta",
  creates => '/usr/bin/pdepend',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install phpmd
exec {"pear install phpmd":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpmd.org/PHP_PMD",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpmd',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}

# install PHP_CodeBrowser
exec {"pear install PHP_CodeBrowser":
  command => "/usr/bin/pear install --alldeps pear.phpqatools.org/PHP_CodeBrowser",
  creates => '/usr/bin/phpcb',
  require => Exec['pear update-channels']
}
}
```

After, I make a vagrant provision

It seems that is all well configured, but when I go to localhost:8888 the page is always loading and not show me the content.

I don't know what I'm doing bad, but I need your help please, the system configuration is not my specialty

Comment: if its a straight install have your tried going to localhost:8888/public as this is where the visual files are kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution. 
There are some incompatibility with Vagrant and VirtualBox in some versions. I don´t know if the issue is for the Guests Aditions.

With vagrant 1.6.2 and VirtualBox 4.3.12 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com) to generate your Puppet manifests? You can enter PEAR modules under the **Languages** section.